# How can I show for which $z \in \mathbb{C}$ it is true, that $|1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2} + ... + \frac{z^p}{p!} + \mathcal{O}(z^{p+1})| < 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My attempt (to show that the $z$ we are looking for are from a bounded space):

We know that every polynomial of degree $p$ has exactly $p$ complex roots. This means, that

$$1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2} + ... + \frac{z^p}{p!} = \alpha (z - z_1) ... (z - z_p)$$

We also know, that $\mathcal{O}(z^{p+1}) \le M z^{p+1}$

So here, we already got:

$$0 \le |1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2} + ... + \frac{z^p}{p!} + \mathcal{O}(z^{p+1})|  \le |\alpha (z - z_1) ... (z - z_p) + M z^{p+1}|  \le $$

$$\le |\alpha| |(z - z_1)| ... |(z - z_p)| + |M| |z|^{p+1}  $$

This again is a polynomial of degree $p+1$, so we get

$$\le |\beta| |(z - z_1^o)| ... |(z - z_{p+1}^o)|$$

We say, that

$$|\beta| |(z - z_1^o)| ... |(z - z_{p+1}^o)| \le 1$$

So we get

$$ 0 \le |\beta| |(z - z_1^o)| ... |(z - z_{p+1}^o)| \le 1$$

This only means that our $z$ must be from a bounded space.

Are my calculations alright up until now?

Comment: (i) Does $p$ range over positive integers, or only primes? I'm guessing integers, but $p$ usually denotes a prime. (ii) It makes no sense to say $|f_p(z)+O(z^{p+1})|<1$ $-$ the $O$ notation can only occur on the right-hand side (not the left-hand side) of an equality (not an inequality). $O()$ is not a quantity; it is a special notation with a special meaning.

Comment: @TonyK (1) $p \in \mathbb{N}_0$ (2) But that's literally the exercise. I need to show that the space of $z$, for which $|R(z)| < 1$ ($R(z)$ is the function of stability of an explicit Runge Kutta method), is bounded. And it happens to be that for an explicit Runge Kutta method, its function of stability is equal to  $R(z) = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2} + ... + \frac{z^p}{p!} + \mathcal{O}(z^{p+1})$

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you can't go from e.g. $(n+1)^3=n^3+O(n^2)$ to $O(n^2)-(n+1)^3=-n^3$. The $O$-notation doesn't work like that. Your equation literally makes no sense.

Comment: @TonyK So instead what should I do here? I've been trying to come up with something for a couple of hours already, but I simply don't have an idea how to prove that the space of such $z$ is bounded

Comment: It looks like you want to find those $z\in\Bbb C$ for which $$\lim\sup\left|\sum_{r=0}^p\frac{z^r}{r!}\right|<1$$ But this series converges for all $z$, to $e^z$, so this is just $\{z\in\Bbb C:|e^z|<1\}$.

Comment: @TonyK And that's why I don't understand this exercise, because we indeed get an unbounded set of possible $z$.

Comment: That's what you get if you put your big-$O$'s on the left-hand side! Your inequality $$\mathcal{O}(z^{p+1}) \le M z^{p+1}$$ is meaningless. (I confess I can't follow your reasoning, but I think the problem is that $M$ depends on $p$, so your argument falls down.)

Comment: @TonyK So let's ignore my inequality $\mathcal{O}(z^{p+1}) \le M z^{p+1}$ for a moment. Is there any way to prove that the space of $z$ for which $|R(z)|<1$ is bounded?

Comment: You need to define what exactly you mean by $$R(z) = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2} + ... + \frac{z^p}{p!} + \mathcal{O}(z^{p+1})$$ Is $p$ fixed? Is $z$ fixed? See Wikipedia's article on [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: @TonyK No, $z$ is not fixed. Yes, $p$ is fixed

Comment: Well then, $O(z^{p+1})$ only makes sense when understood as $O(z^{p+1})$ as $z\to 0$. In other words, it _assumes_ $z$ is bounded; otherwise it makes no sense. Are you following me here?

Comment: @TonyK So this means, there's nothing "to prove" as due to $\mathcal{O}(z^{p+1})$ we already get that the set of $z$ must be bounded (and thus, also that set of $z$ for which $|R(z)|<1$)?

Comment: I would say the opposite: there is nothing that _can_ be proven from the conditions that you give.